# How can I change the properties within a WPF style referenced in another file using a trigger?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, styles, drawing

I have a `DrawingBrush` declared in one file, and a Style declared in another file. The Style uses the `DrawingBrush` as a background fill. Now, in the UserControl XAML file I make reference to the Style via a binding.

```
Style="{DynamicResource myCustomStyle}"
```

Here's the tricky part. I want to use a `DataTrigger` to change the Fill colour of a path within the `DrawingBrush`. Now, since the Style exists within one file and the `DrawingBrush` in another, how would I accomplish this?

I wish to avoid creating multiple `DrawingBrush`es for each colour I need. I want it to be dynamic and reusable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this can't be done. I've experimented with moving the DrawingBrush to a ResourceDictionary and as soon as this is done, the databinding throws an error. If I take the following XAML

```
<Rectangle x:Name="IconBrush" local:Helper.Colour="Black">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <DrawingBrush  Stretch="Uniform">
            <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                <DrawingGroup>
                    <DrawingGroup.Children>
                        <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M1,1 L9.5,1 L9.5,13 L1,13 z M10.5,10.4 L13.15,13 M11.6,7.675 C11.6,9.5113467 10.066575,11 8.175,11 C6.2834248,11 4.75,9.5113467 4.75,7.675 C4.75,5.8386532 6.2834248,4.35 8.175,4.35 C10.066575,4.35 11.6,5.8386532 11.6,7.675 z">
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Thickness="1"
                                     Brush="{Binding Path=(local:Helper.Colour), RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Rectangle}}}" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup.Children>
                </DrawingGroup>
            </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        </DrawingBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

And then change it to this instead, then it stops working. Not sure why it can't be done like this to take advantage of reusable resources.

```
 <Rectangle x:Name="IconBrush" pm4uc:Helper.Colour="Black"
            Fill="{DynamicResource NewIconBrush}" />
```

I guess WPF can't resolve finding ancestors or databinding within a resource dictionary.